# Rust: как запретить автоформат определенному куску кода

Tags: rust, форматирование-кода

Есть несколько частей кода, которые ужасно форматированы автоформатом (скриншоты ниже). Это просто нечитабельный для меня код. Как я могу отключить форматирование для определенной части кода (чтобы сохранить формат, который я установил)?

До:
[image: до]
После:
[image: после]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289474

Comment: Боже, вы мой спаситель! Это пять! Спасибо!!!

Comment: Можете сделать хорошее дело и переписать в ответ, если помогло

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers "Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной" - У меня нет этой серой галочки. Обидно, мне люди помогают уже не первый раз, а я ее (эту галочку) найти не могу.

Comment: Потому что это комментарии к вопросу, а не не ответы. Ниже у вас должна быть кнопка "добавить ответ" или что-то вроде того. И да, вы можете сами отвечать на свои же вопросы.

Comment: Только кнопка "Ответить на собственный вопрос" внизу есть. Вы предлагаете скопировать ваш комментарий и ответить им на собственный вопрос? Это может улучшить ваш рейтинг за помощь мне? Если ваш рейтинг это действие НЕ улучшает, то мне не понятно "можете сделать хорошее дело", для вас же получается бонусов не будет. Извините если что, я тут недавно.

Comment: Вопрос не в моем рейтинге, если бы он был для меня в приоритете, то да, безусловно я бы сам опубликовал ответ. Но мне просто лень. А цель SO - создание общедоступной базы знаний. Мало ли кто будет гуглить подобную проблему и наткнется на ваш вопрос. Именно поэтому лучше опубликовать ответ именно в виде ответа. Только заранее хочу предупредить, что просто ссылка не прокатит. Нужно перевести ответ *и* добавить ссылку на оригинал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#[rustfmt::skip]` [позволяет пропустить «блок» кода при форматировании](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/issues/1322)

Рассмотрим этот код:

```
fn add(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a + b }
fn sub(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a - b }
```

rustfmt отформатирует это так:

```
fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a - b
}
```

Мы можем поместить `#[rustfmt::skip]` над каждой функцией, чтобы rustfmt игнорировал их форматирование:

```
#[rustfmt::skip]
fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 { a + b }

#[rustfmt::skip]
fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 { a - b }
```

P.s. Также удобным решением может быть создание общего модуля с `#[rustfmt::skip]` как в примере ниже:

```
#[rustfmt::skip]
mod unformatted {
    pub fn add(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a + b }
    pub fn sub(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a - b }
}

use unformatted::*;

fn main() {
    dbg!(add(2, 3));
}
```

[Данный ответ представляет собой перевод ответа на сходный вопрос на сайте stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288537/how-can-i-switch-off-rustfmt-for-a-region-of-code-instead-of-a-single-item)

Comment: Минимальный пример пришелся бы очень кстати.

Comment: Вот. Отличный ответ. Еще и со своим примером. А почему решением не отмечаете? Все по делу ведь.